# Is ng2-pdf-viewer@8.0.1 compitable with @angular/cli@10.2.4

Tags: angular, ng2-pdf-viewer

I'm using angular/cli@10.2.4 and upgrading ng2-pdf-viewer to version@8.0.1 but i got error

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZnJ.png)

What is this error and how to solve it?

I've tried to disable ivy but it didn't work with me.
the working version is ng2-pdf-viewer@6.4.1

But i need this version@8.0.1